# How to create Quartz.Net Job from lambda?

Tags: c#, quartz.net

Is it possible to create a job from a lambda in Quartz.net?

I have a lot of tasks I need to run, and I'd really like to avoid having to create dozens of classes one for each job. I don't have any need for any advanced setting, I just need to call a method every now and then.

```
scheduler.ScheduleJob(() => DoSomething(a), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
scheduler.ScheduleJob(() => DoAnotherThing(b), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
scheduler.ScheduleJob(() => DoThis(c), TimeSpan.FromHours(2));
scheduler.ScheduleJob(() => DoThat(d), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
...
```

I'd create a extension method for this, but it seems each job requires it's own type to be able to create an IJob, and this makes things harder than they should be.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: by the way, `() => Foo()`, is equivalent to just writing `Foo`. The parentheses cancel out

Comment: @Natan There is no such thing in Quartz.Net, you need to write it yourself. Maybe the [JobFactory](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/tutorial/miscellaneous-features.html) could help you to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I was missing jobdata for parameters. I was able to accomplish this with the following code, if anyone needs it:

```
using Quartz;
using System;

namespace MyApp
{
    public static class SchedulerExtensions
    {
        public static DateTimeOffset ScheduleJob(this IScheduler scheduler, Action action, TimeSpan initialDelay, TimeSpan interval)
        {
            var data = new JobDataMap();
            data.Add("_", action);

            var jobDetail = JobBuilder.Create<GenericJob>().UsingJobData(data).Build();

            var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .StartAt(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Add(initialDelay))
                .WithSimpleSchedule(s => s.WithInterval(interval).RepeatForever())
                .Build();

            return scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
        }

        class GenericJob : IJob
        {
            public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
            {
                (context.JobDetail.JobDataMap["_"] as Action)?.Invoke();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have problem with this code. http://prntscr.com/e8wbhn ; I'm trying to call ForceScheduledCheck() once per day at the same time. But job is not runned at the needed time. Have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Wrote a little extention library which allows to sue lambda syntax.

```
scheduler.ScheduleJob(() => Console.WriteLine("With TriggerBuilder"), 
 builder => builder.StartNow()
 .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
    .WithIntervalInSeconds(10)
    .RepeatForever()));

scheduler.ScheduleJob(() => Console.WriteLine("With int delay and interval"), 0, 10);
```

Nuget:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Quartz.Lambda/

Github:
https://github.com/midianok/Quartz.Lambda/